# Another opportunity to help improve the close process

Tags: discussion

There's another post on MetaStackOverflow asking for input to improvements to the closing process, if anyone wants to provide some input.

[Help us make "Not Constructive" and "Not a Real Question" closures more effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171732/195988)